# VS Code - LaTeX-Workshop - Recipe with `for` script

Tags: compiling, scripts, vscode, visual-studio-code

#### Hello There

Currently creating compilation recipes for LaTeX-Workshop extension in visual studio code, how to create a tool that rename files using `for` and  `mv` or some other method?

The script using a terminal on mac would be pretty simple:

```
for file in ./*.tex; do mv $file `echo $file | tr ' ' '_'`; done
```

The tools used in the recipe would be something similar to:

```
{
    "name": "' '->'_'",
    "command": "for",
    "args": [
        "file",
        "in",
        "./**.tex;",
        "do",
        "mv",
        "$file",
        "`echo $file | tr ' ' '_'`;",
        "done",
    ],
    "env": {}
},
{
    "name": "'_'->' '",
    "command": "for",
    "args": [
        "file",
        "in",
        "./**.tex;",
        "do",
        "mv",
        "$file",
        "`echo $file | tr '_' ' '`;",
        "done",
    ],
    "env": {}
},
```

and the recipe would be:

```
{
    "name": "lualatex light",
    "tools": [
        "' '->'_'",
        "lualatex",
        "'_'->' '"
    ]
},
```

The way it currently is, the compilation generates the following error:

```
[16:05:21] LaTeX build process spawned. PID: undefined.
[16:05:21] LaTeX fatal error: spawn for ENOENT, . PID: undefined.
[16:05:21] Does the executable exist? $PATH: /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
[16:05:21] Does the executable exist? $Path: undefined
[16:05:21] The environment variable $SHELL: /bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because, it seems, tool args cannot contain commands, just args for the command identified in that tool.  For example, your `for` command's args contain the `echo` command.

Secondly, if the first tool of your recipe worked, then `lualatex` would not work because it looks for your main TeX file, which (temporarily) does not exist because you renamed it.  I base this claim on the assumption that your `lualatex` tool is defined in your settings.json file as something like the following, which invokes `%DOC%`, which points to your project's main TeX file:

```json
        {
            "name": "lualatex",
            "command": "lualatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        },
```

**You have a couple options to get around this issue**

1. You can compile normally via `lualatex` while working on your project.  When you are ready to share the generated PDF with whomever wants underscores instead of spaces in the file name, run this command in your terminal (assuming your filename is `M W E.pdf`):

`mv M\ W\ E.pdf $(echo "M W E.pdf" | tr ' ' '_')`

2. You can have a shell script that does this renaming for you and your LaTeX Workshop recipe calls a tool that simply runs this shell script.

Shell script rename.sh saved in the same directory as `%DIR%` and given execute permissions with `chmod 755 rename.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
mv "${1}" $(echo $1 | tr ' ' '_')
```

Tool:

```json
        {
            "name": "rename",
            "command": "./rename.sh",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%.pdf",
            ],
        },
```

Recipe:

```json
        {
            "name": "lualatex light",
            "tools": [
                "lualatex",
                "rename",
            ]
        },
```

---

This might be possible in an automated way completely organic to VS Code and LaTeX Workshop if there was a way to pipe the output of one tool to another.  For example, the code and variations on it produces these files:

```json
        {
            "name": "' '->'_'",
            "command": "mv",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%.pdf",
                "$(echo %DOCFILE%.pdf | tr ' ' '_')",
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
```

[image: screen shot of generated files]